# Why can an autowired Spark Function be not accessed from inside another Spark Function

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using a Spark filter Function f1 (call() method) inside another Spark Function f2. I am autowiring the function object f1. But this is ultimately throwing Task Not Serializable. Then, when I assigned this object to another local variable, it is working fine. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here, but it feels that I have a misconception regarding this.

Below, I have provided the working and not working code.

This is the filter function (f1):

```
@Bean(name = "lengthFilter")
public Function<String, Boolean> lengthFilter(@Value("${record.length:31}") String recordLength){
    return i -> !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(i) && i.length() == Integer.valueOf(recordLength);
}
```

Not working code:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("lengthFilter")
private Function<String, Boolean> lengthFilter;

JavaDStream<String> records = messages.map(t -> t._2());


records.mapToPair(s -> {

        if(lengthFilter.call(s)) {
            return new Tuple2<>(s.substring(0,2), s);
        } else {
            return new Tuple2<>("default", s);
        }

    });
```

This code is throwing Spark Exception saying that the task is not Serializable.

Working Code:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("lengthFilter")
private Function<String, Boolean> lengthFilter;


Function<String,Boolean> lengthFilterLocal = lengthFilter;

JavaDStream<String> records = messages.map(t -> t._2());


records.mapToPair(s -> {

    if(lengthFilterLocal.call(s)) {
        return new Tuple2<>(s.substring(0,2), s);
    } else {
        return new Tuple2<>("default", s);
    }

});
```

The first one fails with exception saying the task cannot be serialized, while the second one executes successfully. The only difference between the two codes is that in the second one, the autowired Function is assigned to a local variable and that variable is accessed from inside the mapToPair(). I want to know what is the reason behind this or where am I going wrong.